# Fingerprint GUI breaks lock screen after suspend

Tags: suspend, lock-screen, fingerprint-reader

ASUS M50Vc with AuthenTec AES1600 fingerprint reader, Ubuntu 14.04.

Everything works normally EXCEPT when I need to unlock the screen after suspend. There is no prompt to swipe the finger, swiping doesn't do anything, if I try unlock with password, the "wait" indicator keeps rotating but screen won't get unlocked (it doesn't hang though, panel still accessible).

Has anyone had a similar issue? Any workaround suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

@Pavel, I just came across the same issue with my ThinkPad X220 here, running Ubuntu 14.10. A temporary workaround for me is to switch to the (non-graphical) console, log in there with my password, kill the `fingerprint-helper` process and then switch back to the X-server console.

Steps are:

1. Switch to the text console: `Ctrl + Alt + F1`
2. Login with your regular username + password
3. Shutdown the blocking process: `killall fingerprint-helper`
4. Switch back to the X-server console: `Alt + F7`

If this is not sufficient, you might want to try killing `fingerprint-polkit-agent` as well, although it hasn't been necessary when I tried today.

Don't forget to log off from the text console again (press `Ctrl + D`), otherwise everyone else who has physical access to the machine will be able to use it!

Comment: I stopped using fingerprint login, will re-install & try again.

Comment: Same behavior here with Thinkpad x230 (Upek Fingerprint reader 0x147e:2020) and Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I also usually kill the fingerprint-helper as he1ix wrote when it hangs. But I have one question, do you use encrypted home filesystem with ecryptfs? I do.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues, but just hitting enter after swiping my finger makes it work. Using a thinkpad x1 though (from 2011?), so might be different.