# After returning from suspend, Ubuntu will not accept password even though it is correct.

Tags: password, suspend

I have only had Ubuntu 14.04 installed for a couple weeks. A couple days ago, whenever I would return from suspend, the password would not be accepted. However, if I restarted my computer, typing the exact same password would work just fine. Any possible way to figure out what is causing this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. If I switch from the X tty, e.g. [Ctrl]+[Alt]+6 and then switch back [Ctrl]+[Alt]+7, I can login without problem.

Answer (score 0):

My comment also works as a partial answer.

After you come back from suspend do the following:

1. `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+F6` to leave the X session. You don't have to type anything in to the terminal that appears.
2. `[Ctrl]+[Alt]+F7` to come back to the X session. Now you can input the password and it validates properly.

It's not a fix, but a lot easier than rebooting.

Comment: When I am in the log in screen, [Ctrl]+[Alt]+6 doesn't do anything. I found if I switch accounts and type my password in, it says it failed but then the screen goes blank and after a couple seconds I'm logged in.

Comment: @rcon197 Ooops, that should be F6 and F7 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only switching to the text console and then back to the graphical one has not been sufficient. On top of this, I had to log in at the text console and shutdown the `fingerprint-helper` process from there. After switching back to the X-server console, I was able to continue using my session.

For details, please see my answer on [Fingerprint GUI breaks lock screen after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531165/fingerprint-gui-breaks-lock-screen-after-suspend/565216#565216).