# Fingerprint reader after suspend

Tags: login, suspend, fingerprint-reader

After resuming from suspend the fingerprint reader is not ready for input (the little green LED is off thinkpad x201t) even though the text to use the fprint reader is shown (swipe you right index finger across the fingerprint reader), but I can not log in.

If I wait until the authentication is switched to keyboard and I hit enter, the fingerprint reader text is shown again, the greed LED is on and I can log in using the fingerprint reader.

If I just lock the screen everything works as expected.

I am using fprintd (0.5.1-1) and Ubuntu 14.04.

It seems the problem is, that the fingerprint reader does not get turned on correctly after the suspend.

Comment: Same problem on a X230 (Ubuntu 14.04) here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem on my X220, in my case it helps to kill the `fingerprint-helper` process to resume my session. However, I'm not seeing the behaviour you're describing with the fingerprint reader text being shown after waiting and hitting enter then... On the other hand, the lock screen behaves the same as in your case.

Did you have a look at Ubuntu [bug report #1310104](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1310104)?

In case you're interested in the steps required in my case, have a look at my answer here: [Fingerprint GUI breaks lock screen after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531165/fingerprint-gui-breaks-lock-screen-after-suspend/565216#565216).

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but a good workaround:

Turning on the on screen keyboard in the Universal Access settings (typing) brings up the old school login screen, which has no problems with the finger print readerh